# Box2D get collision impulse WITHOUT b2ContactListener

Tags: c++, box2d

Is there any way in Box2D to get the impulse of a collision without registering a contact listener?

Ie, I can get a list of all contacts for a body using `GetContactList()` and `contact->GetManifold()->localNorm`, but this returns a unit vector.

I couldn't seem to find any way of getting the impulse information from the `b2Contact` class.

Answer (score 0):

No, there may be more than one impulse per time step. Use a listener.

Comment: Just like there may be more than one contact norm per time-step? But I can still access contact norms without a listener.

Comment: I am not sure what that contactnorm is from. It may be that you're looking at the last contact. I'm not sure you can do much of anything useful with it.